# Connecting svg id with select option id

Tags: angular

I'm developing a reservation seats app in Angular and I have a component with inside an svg that contain some squares that represents seats, each one have an id.
In another component I have a modal with a drop down select that contain all the numbers of seats.
When I select a number from the drop down I want to fill the square of a specific square how can I do?

I've searched how to do but I didn't find nothing
I'm trying to connect the id of the svg square with the id of the number of seat.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine you has a simple svg like

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 320 120" version="1.1"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g id="id1"><circle cx="60" cy="60" r="50"/></g>
  <g id="id2"><circle cx="160" cy="60" r="50"/></g>
  <g id="id3"><circle cx="260" cy="60" r="50"/></g>
</svg>
```

The important part is that the "g" has an attributte "id"

1. We can use the .svg in the own .html

   ```
   <select [ngModel]="seatSelected" 
      (ngModelChange)="seatSelected=$event;select($event)">
     <option value="id1">Seat A</option>
     <option value="id2">Seat B</option>
     <option value="id3">Seat C</option>
   </select>
   <div style="width:20%">
   <svg viewBox="0 0 320 120" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" (click)="selectSeat($event.target)">
     <g id="id1"><circle cx="60" cy="60" r="50"/></g>
     <g id="id2"><circle cx="160" cy="60" r="50"/></g>
     <g id="id3"><circle cx="260" cy="60" r="50"/></g>
   </svg>
   </div>
   ```

   We can use a directive to allow more easy mannage the seats. The
   directive expose the "id" and the "elementRef" as public. It's
   simply like

   ```
   @Directive({
     selector: 'g[id]'
   })
   export class SvgGroupDirective {
     id:string
     constructor(public el:ElementRef) { 
       this.id=this.el.nativeElement.getAttribute('id')
     }
   }
   ```

   then we can manange the seats in the way

   ```
    @ViewChildren(SvgGroupDirective) seats:QueryList<SvgGroupDirective>
    seatSelected:string;
     select(id:string)
     {
        //we iterate over all the "seats"
        this.seats.forEach(x=>{
           x.el.nativeElement.style.fill=x.id==id?'red':'black'
        })
     }

     selectSeat(target:any)
     {
       //we search the "seat" that contains the "target"
       //the target will be the "circle element"

       const seat=this.seats.find(x=>x.el.nativeElement.contains(target))
       if (seat)
       {
          this.seatSelected=this.seatSelected==seat.id?null:seat.id
          this.select(this.seatSelected)
       }
     }
   ```
2. If you really has a file.svg, we need load ans use DomSanitizer to
   give value to an innerHTML of a div

   ```
   constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,private http: HttpClient){}
     seatSelected2:string;
     logoHtml:any;
     //in ngOnInit
     ngOnInit()
     {
       this.http.get('/assets/circles.svg', { responseType: 'text' })
               .subscribe(logo => {
                   this.logoHtml = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(logo);
               });
     }
   ```

   the .html

   ```
    <div style="width:20%" [innerHtml]="logoHtml" 
        (click)="selectSeat2($event.target)">
   </div>
   ```

   Our functions use `document.getElementsByTagName('g')` to get the
   "seats"

   ```
    select2(id:string)
    {
       const seats=document.getElementsByTagName('g')
       for ( var i = 0; i < seats.length; i++) {
         const seat=seats[i]
         const idSeat=seat.getAttribute('id')
         if (idSeat)
          seat.style.fill=idSeat==id?'red':'black'
      }
    }
    selectSeat2(target:any)
    {
      const seats=document.getElementsByTagName('g')
      for ( var i = 0; i < seats.length; i++) {
        const seat=seats[i]
        if (seat.contains(target))
        { 
          const id=seat.getAttribute('id')
          this.seatSelected2=this.seatSelected2==id?null:id
          this.select2(this.seatSelected2)
        }
     }
    }
   ```

NOTE: I suppose the seat have a "id" in a `<g>` tag. If there're others `<g>`s that have "id" we need check before make something that the "id" was "special", e.g. If the ids are in the way `id="seat1"`, we chan check if (id.substr(0,4)=="seat") to only work with the seats

The [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-klvxbs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) with the two approach

Comment: thanks, now i try to use the first  method, the only difference is that i have the svg in another component and i display it under the dropdown. is better to pass the data with a Subject or with Input/EventEmitter?

Comment: @Ommy97, If there're a relationship children/parent, in my opinion, it's more "natural" use Input/EventEmitter else you has only the option to create a service (inject in constructor in both component) and use a Subject in the service. (I just update the stackblitz with this approach, you see that it's only use a getter and add ngAfterViewInit to draw initial value -only after ngAfterViewInit you have the "seats"-)

Comment: thank you very much, you have been very kind.